# Somehow I can't get my VB.net application to exit if it can't run things in the combox list index

Tags: vb.net

So below is the code snippet from my program I made myself and I can't get the program to exit when the progress bar reaches one hundred percent; after checking if there is a valid file to run in the selected index in the combo box.

```
Private Sub CheckIfRunning()
    p = Process.GetProcessesByName(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = TabIndex)
    If p.Count > 0 Then
        ' Process is running
        Else
           Dim did_an_oopsie As DialogResult = Form3.ShowDialog
           If did_an_oopsie = Form3.ProgressBar1.Value = 100 Then
               Close()
           End If
           Try
               Process.Start(System.IO.Path.Combine(
         AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = TabIndex))
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the return value of `Form3.ShowDialog`?

Comment: 1) This likely has nothing to do with the problem in hand but you do realize that `ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = TabIndex` returns a `Boolean` and not a `String`, right? 2) Never swallow exceptions (especially when you're debugging a problem).

Comment: This makes no sense: `If did_an_oopsie = Form3.ProgressBar1.Value = 100 Then`.  `did_an_oopsie` is type `DialogResult` so how does it make sense to compare that to anything other than a `DialogResult` value?  You should start by turning `Option Strict On` and fix all the errors it flags.  You then need to consider what you're actually trying to achieve with that line of code.  Whatever it is, you're not achieving it with that code.

Comment: What is in `Form3` ? and why do you want to get a `DialogResult` from it?

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime. Do this first and then look at your code again. Fix any errors it shows and repost your code.

Comment: The Close() method closes the current Form, not necessarily the application. It depends how you set up the properties of the application and whether there are any other forms open. It won't matter because the code will never reach that line.

Comment: Comment for GetProcessByName need parameter string, so you must change your paramter like this:  dim p = Process.GetProcessesByName(ComboBox1.Items(TabIndex).ToString)

Comment: What did you do in Form3 and when will be closed? Because without close the form3 you can't perform the next process, because next process will wait until form3 close. For your did_an_oopsie, you must set DialogResult of form3 to some enum dialogresult constant in your form3 before you close your form3